# How to trigger Quill JS's Mention Module when a button is clicked

Tags: quill

I'm using this **quill mention module** for my  quill editor: https://github.com/afry/quill-mention.

My editor toolbar has an "@" button, and I was hoping that what if I click that the mention-list will appear.

Was thinking my code will be something like this:

```
$("button.mention-btn").on("click", triggerMention);

function triggerMention(){
  if(!quill.hasFocus()){
    quill.focus();
  }

  evt1 = $.Event('keydown');
  evt1.which = 16; // shift
  evt2 = $.Event('keypress');
  evt2.which = 50; // 2

  quill.trigger(evt1);
  quil.trgger(evt2);

}
```

Can someone with quill-js experience please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found a mention about how to do it in the docs. There is a `openMenu('@')` function for that: https://github.com/afry/quill-mention#methods

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [docs](https://github.com/afry/quill-mention#methods.), the method `openMenu(denotationChar)`:

> Opens the mentions menu for the given denotation character.

In order to call this method, we need to retrieve the module from Quill like: `quill.getModule('mention')`.

The following code should work:

```js
function showMenu() {
  quillEditor.getModule("mention").openMenu("@");
}
```

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/andreivictor/pen/yLbjPaQ

Comment: Any way to do this without needing the `@` character so it can be opened purely programmatically?

Comment: Don't think it's possible, because the method above, internally (see: https://github.com/afry/quill-mention/blob/master/src/quill.mention.js#L733), just inserts the dennotationChar in the editor, and then the editor reacts as the character was typed by the user.

Comment: Hmmmm - I wonder if I can fork the code to include a more programmatic method of opening, rather than using a `denoationChar`